# How to use browserify on node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I've try to browserify the module [wcwidth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcwidth)

I've executed this code:

```
npm install wcwidth
npm install -g browserify
cd node_modules/wcwidth
browserify index.js -o wcwidth.js
```

it generated the file `wcwidth.js` but when I included the file in the html page I don't have access to `wcwidth` function, I've got error that `wcwidth` is undefined.

What else I need to do in order to use node module in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a file:

```
window.wcwidth = require('./');
```

save it in `wcwidth.js` and run:

```
browserify wcwidth.js -o dist/wcwidth.js
```